# Error while starting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

Hello i am new to ruby and rails ... but when i am starting the rail server i am getting this error

This is the error i am getting

```
D:\mynewapp>ruby script/server
```

=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': n
such file to load -- rush (MissingSourceFile)
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:156:in`block in require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
        from D:/mynewapp/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.7.0/lib/delayed/worker.r
1:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:156:in`block in require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
        from D:/mynewapp/vendor/gems/delayed_job-1.7.0/lib/delayed_job.rb:6
n `<top (required)>'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:156:in`block in require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
        from D:/mynewapp/config/environment.rb:39:in `block in <top (requir
)>'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:1
:in`run'
        from D:/mynewapp/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:156:in`block in require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_s
port/dependencies.rb:156:in`require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.
:84:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
require'
        from script/server:3:in`'

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears to be that the server is complaining about a missing file called 'rush' (n such file to load -- rush)

and with some search I found that it is a ruby replacement for the unix shell

http://rush.heroku.com/

so try to install 'rush' gem and see (as @Said proposed) via the Gem file

http://rubygems.org/gems/rush

Following articles will also be useful

http://rush.heroku.com/rdoc/
http://www.slideshare.net/adamwiggins/rush-the-ruby-shell-and-unix-integration-library
http://www.rubyinside.com/rush-a-ruby-shell-that-abstracts-system-operations-into-ruby-ones-765.html

HTH